# Información asociada a los personajes en Scratch Jr

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

estoy investigando el código de Scratch Jr. No encuentro en ningún sitio información acerca de los personajes. Quisiera saber dónde se encuentra el tamaño de cada personaje, la fotografía que utilizan, en resumen, toda la información asociada a un personaje en Scratch Jr. Gracias

Comment: buscas exactamente hacerla grande al inicio o en mitad de la ejecucion?

Comment: si te refieres a los métodos shrink y grow, sé donde están, gracias. Me refiero a la información en detalle, por ejemplo, el gato qué altura tiene en píxeles o en coordenadas, donde se encuentra su imagen para la carga en la pantalla, etc con cada uno de los personajes. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hola Eva.. esto es javascript?

Answer (score 1):

He realizado una busqueda bastante exaustiva en internet, en las wikis oficiales de scratch, foros y demas... Lo unico que he conseguido encontrar es lo siguiente:

[image: Tamaño gato Scratch]

96 x 100 pixeles el gato de scratch normal, de scratch jr hablan menos aun.

Siento no poder serte de mas ayuda.

Comment: me podrías decir dónde has encontrado eso? si en algún foro (¿cuál?) o en el propio código. Gracias, hay muy poca información, y claro para poder utilizarlos bien me gustaría conocer todas sus características, además que en algún sitio tienen que estar ¿no? Gracias de todas formas

Comment: Siento decirte que no guarde la referencia y por mas que estoy buscando no encuentro... Fue en un foro, si